# Java generics - too complicated? How to simplify?

Tags: java, generics, design-patterns

Originally I had posted the question on CodeReview, but this is more suited for StackOverflow probably.

I'm coding for a multi-step process, using Java 6. Say there are 3 of these steps.
Each accepts the same type of input.
Lets begin.

This is the object which is passed as input to each step. This object acts as a wrapper for another type of object, alongside some steps' shared values.
Be aware names are  translated to a more generic domain and in english, originals are in Italian.

```
public class EntityStepInput<T extends Entity> {
    public final T entity;
    public boolean modified;
    public boolean canceled;

    public EntityStepInput(final T entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }
}
```

This is the interface used by each step.

```
public interface EntityStep<T extends EntityStepInput<? extends Entity>> {
    void process(final T stepInput) throws Exception;
}
```

Now, 2 out of the 3 steps must accept an `EntityStepInput` which contains a `Entity` or any type derived from it.

```
public class FirstEntityStep implements EntityStep<EntityStepInput<? extends Entity>> {
    @Override
    public void process(final EntityStepInput<? extends Entity> stepInput) throws Exception {}
}

public class SecondEntityStep implements EntityStep<EntityStepInput<? extends Entity>> {
    @Override
    public void process(final EntityStepInput<? extends Entity> stepInput) throws Exception {}
}
```

The last step must accept an `EntityStepInput` which contains a specific type derived from `Entity`.

```
public class ThirdEntityStep implements EntityStep<EntityStepInput<? extends DerivedEntity>> {
    @Override
    public void process(final EntityStepInput<? extends DerivedEntity> stepInput) throws Exception {}
}
```

The usage is pretty straighforward. I have overloaded methods which accept different types of `Entity`s. What follows is a simplified version.

```
public void workWithEntity(final DerivedEntity entity) throws Exception {
    final EntityStepInput<DerivedEntity> stepInput = new EntityStepInput<DerivedEntity>(entity);

    stepOne.process(stepInput);
    stepTwo.process(stepInput);
    stepThree.process(stepInput);
}
```

As you can see the `DerivedEntity` type is able to use all of the steps.

```
public void workWithEntity(final OtherDerivedEntity entity) throws Exception {
    final EntityStepInput<OtherDerivedEntity> stepInput = new EntityStepInput<OtherDerivedEntity>(entity);

    stepOne.process(stepInput);
    stepTwo.process(stepInput);
}
```

And here another type of `Entity` cannot use the last step, which is what I want.

Now, this has became quite complex with generics. I fear who will read my code after I'm gone won't understand and sooner or later a mess is going to be made.

Is this simplifiable? What would your approach be like to respect as much as possibile the single responsibility principle?

Edit. `Entity` hierarchy is as follow:

```
Entity > DerivedEntity
Entity > OtherDerivedEntity
```

Comment: @Jacob G. I saw you posted a comment but I couldn't read it, could you post it here?

Comment: Sure, I said "Honestly, it looks fine as it is. If I come up with anything better, I'll post a new answer."  Because you want the third process to only accept `? extends DerivedEntity`, I'm not sure how much else can be done without the use of generic types (other than having a `Consumer<? extends Entity>[]` and using `instanceof`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One smaller change is just to simplify the type variable declaration on `EntityStep` to an `Entity` instead of an `EntityStepInput`:

```
interface EntityStep<E extends Entity> {
    void process(EntityStepInput<? extends E> i);
}
```

And then:

```
class FirstEntityStep implements EntityStep<Entity> {
    @Override
    public void process(EntityStepInput<? extends Entity> i) {}
}
class SecondEntityStep implements EntityStep<Entity> {
    @Override
    public void process(EntityStepInput<? extends Entity> i) {}
}
class ThirdEntityStep implements EntityStep<DerivedEntity> {
    @Override
    public void process(EntityStepInput<? extends DerivedEntity> i) {}
}
```

It's exactly the same as before, but the declarations are a bit easier to understand.

You'd only need `T extends EntityStepInput<...>` if you wanted to use some specific subclass, but since you always use `EntityStepInput` directly, you don't need it.

Comment: That's it! I think we're at the limit

Answer (score 3):

Here's my second attempt at an answer.  I think the system that you're using currently looks good; it provides compile-time checking, as you don't want to allow Step #3 to attempt to process any type which is not a `DerivedEntity` (or one of its children).

You can simplify this by using a `List<Consumer<? extends Entity>>`, but you lose compile-time type checking for Step #3 and are forced to ameliorate it by using `instanceof`:

Java 8+ solution:

```
List<Consumer<Entity>> processes = new ArrayList<>();

processes.add(entity -> {
    // Process first step.
});

processes.add(entity -> {
    // Process second step.
});

processes.add(entity -> {
    if (!(entity instanceof DerivedEntity)) {
        System.out.println("Step 3: The entity must be a DerivedEntity!");
        return;
    }
    // Process third step.
});
```

To pass an `Entity` through the pipeline, it's as simple as:

```
processes.forEach(consumer -> consumer.accept(entity));
```

---

Java 6+ solution (let's create our own `Consumer` interface!):

```
public interface Consumer<T> {
    void accept(T t);
}
```

The same code as above, but using our `Consumer` interface:

```
List<Consumer<Entity>> processes = new ArrayList<Consumer<Entity>>();

processes.add(new Consumer<Entity>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Entity entity) {
        // Process first step.
    }
});

processes.add(new Consumer<Entity>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Entity entity) {
        // Process second step.
    }
});

processes.add(new Consumer<Entity>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(Entity entity) {
        if (!(entity instanceof DerivedEntity)) {
            System.out.println("Step 3: The entity must be a DerivedEntity!");
            return;
        }
        // Process third step.
    }
});

Entity entity = new DerivedEntity();

for (Consumer<Entity> consumer : processes) {
    consumer.accept(entity);
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that looks good, especially if one can simply call each step one after the other, as you now showed with your last edit! This is a good solution if you can cope with using instanceof and if you're on Java 8+.

Comment: OP did state he uses Java 6 though.

Comment: @JacobG. Keep the Java 8 one too. Might come handy to someone else