# Constructor over-injection and Facade Service concept

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a pretty simple interface which manages the update of business proposals, specifically during a nightly batch process each record is submitted here (but it might be used in other scenarios).
This interface is used inside an EJB 2.0 Bean, which fetches records and "cycles" them.
Beware names are translated from Italian to English so pardon possible errors. I also simplified some concepts.

```
public interface ProposalUpdateService {
    void updateProposal(final ProposalFirstType proposal);
    void updateProposal(final ProposalSecondType proposal);
}
```

The implementation of this interface has quite a lot of dependencies:

```
public class ProposalUpdateDefaultService implements ProposalUpdateService {
    private final ComplexService complexService;
    private final OtherComplexService otherComplexService;

    private final ProposalStep<Proposal> stepOne;
    private final ProposalStep<Proposal> stepTwo;
    private final ProposalStep<ProposalTypeTwo> stepThree;
    private final ProposalStep<Proposal> stepFour;

    public ProposalUpdateDefaultService(
            final ComplexService complexService,
            final OtherComplexService otherComplexService,
            final YetAnotherComplexService yetAnotherComplexService,
            final SimpleService simpleService,
            final OtherSimpleService otherSimpleService,
            final YetAnotherSimpleService yetAnotherSimpleService,
            final Converter<ProposalTypeOne, ComplexServiceType> converterProposalTypeOne,
            final Converter<ProposalTypeTwo, OtherComplexServiceType> converterProposalTypeTwo) {
        this.complexService = complexService;
        this.otherComplexService = otherComplexService;

        stepOne = new StepOne(yetAnotherComplexService);
        stepTwo =
                new StepTwo(
                        complexService,
                        otherComplexService,
                        yetAnotherComplexService,
                        converterProposalTypeOne,
                        converterProposalTypeTwo);
        stepThree =
                new StepThree(
                        simpleService,
                        otherSimpleService,
                        yetAnotherSimpleService);
        stepFour = new StepFour();
    }

    ...
```

As you can see this class encapsulate the update of a `Proposal` object, and this process is splitted in four phases, each representing a single concept (such as, "should this proposal be expired?" or "should I advance its state?"). Those four phases may be arranged differently between different types of `Proposal`.

Here is the highly simplified implementation of those two `updateProposal` methods:

```
@Override
public void updateProposal(final ProposalTypeOne proposal) {
   stepOne.process(proposal);
   stepTwo.process(proposal);

   if (...) {
      stepFour.process(proposal);
   }
}

@Override
public void updateProposal(final ProposalTypeTwo proposal) {
   stepOne.process(proposal);
   stepTwo.process(proposal);
   stepThree.process(proposal);
   stepFour.process(proposal);
}
```

The two private fields

```
private final ComplexService complexService;
private final OtherComplexService otherComplexService;
```

are used for helper private methods.

As you can see this class just organize and delegate work, however, it does depend on too many other classes. The same could be said for certain `ProposalStep`(s).

The `*Service`(s) are used inside each step to retrieve details from the database, to update dependent entries, etc.

Would you accept this number of dependencies?
How would you refactor to simplify?

I've read about the Facade Service concept as a way to reduce dependencies, and how I should group cluster of dependencies together, but here I don't really understand what to do.

I may group the `Converter`(s) and the `Service`(s) which uses them, but they'll be too many anyway.

Let me know if other details are needed.

Comment: there are multiple ways to reduce the complexity of a class in terms of responsibility and dependencies but here you don't provide enough input about the way which the dependencies are used to provide you specific advises. Besides this question doesn't suit to SO. This one is better : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @davidxxx I've tried many times CodeReview (with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51340234/java-generics-too-complicated-how-to-simplify for example), and I've found SO a better place. Let me know which type of details you need and I'll provide them.

Comment: @davidxxx I've clarified what those *Service(s) are used for.

Comment: @davidxxx _"Here is the highly simplified implementation of those two updateProposal methods"_ means this is hypothetical/stub code which is off-topic at Code Review.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger and obviously I cannot disclose the actual code.

Comment: And that's perfectly fine. You have a specific programming problem and you come to SO with a minimal example reproducing the problem. It's just that more often than not, people are redirecting questions to Code Review where they are likely to be closed.

Comment: @Mathias Ettinger and OP : as the code is working we generally encourage to post in Code Review. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211788/code-review-vs-stackoverflow  And this appears to be the case here. The op didn't encounter a difficulty to do something, he/she wonder if he/she should change something. Note that generally I am not very strict on the boundaries between them.

Comment: @davidxxx In this case incorrectly though. Please take a look at [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: In the end it doesn't matter. Usually CodeReview closes these questions, and here on SO they're unlikely to receive many answers.

Comment: @LppEdd Personally I would like to help you but as explained initially it lacks really relevant information to write a fine answer or give useful pointers.  You describe broadly how the dependencies are used. It is not enough : you need to explain the overall logic done by the dependencies. Only with that we could help you to reorganize the design. A design or a refactoring makes sense according to a requirement that is provided by artifacts as the workflow.

Comment: @davidxxx you're right. I'll explain more.

Comment: @davidxxx would posting each Step implementation (simplified) be helpful?

Comment: At this time it is not necessary I think. But for the `ProposalUpdateDefaultService` class we don't know which dependencies are only required for Steps and which are required both for Steps and ProposalUpdateDefaultService.  You should add this information.

Comment: @davidxxx there is! If you look at where I wrote "The two private fields..." I state that two dependencies are used for helper private methods.

Comment: I was not sure of the meaning of that. It is clear now. In this case, why do you overuse the constructor to pass dependencies to dependencies? It increases its complexity and its role. Why don't use a service locator to retrieve the dependencies in the scope of the Steps ?

Comment: @davidxxx isn't the Service Locator an anti-pattern? Something to avoid? It is the strategy used for EJB 2.x Beans and they literally cannot be tested without a mocking framework (in reality they can't be tested anyway)

Comment: In fact, it is not the best pattern to retrieve dependencies but as you cannot/don't want to use dependency injection, it is so the way to follow. Note that a locator service doesn't mean static methods. It should provide instance methods.  So mocking it with natural mock feature is very simple.

Comment: @davidxxx I need to think and analyze a little bit. I'll comment here later. Thanks =)

Comment: @davidxxx I posted my answer. What do you think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I found more convenient is just removing the `ProposalUpdateService` abstraction, and letting the EJB Bean manage the various steps.

This abstraction layer was unnecessary as of now, and each step is still usable individually. Both `ProposalUpdateService` method invocations become private methods in the EJB Bean.

Comment: In fact you have split the logic of the two methods into two EJB beans. It sounds an improvement. (+1)

Comment: @davidxxx Not really. There is still a single EJB Bean, because the public interface is a single method "updateAllProposals()". The ProposalUpdateService has been "merged" with the EJB Bean.

Comment: Ah ok. So do you mean that you pulled up the logic in the caller layer ?

Comment: @davidxxx exactly! PS: the caller (the EJB Bean) IS the business logic layer

Comment: The delegation was maybe too artificial. Just ensure that the EJB bean doesn't make too many things and that it focuses on orchestrating things rather than doing things.

Comment: @davidxxx Thanks! It does almost nothing, it only has a couple of helper methods. Everything is delegated to the steps. The abstraction layer I had introduced was meant to be testable (unlike the EJB Bean), but I can test each step invidually.

Comment: It seems to be the right way to get a robust and maintainable code. And you seem to care unit testing, I like that :)

Comment: @davidxxx Unfortunately unit testing is a personal thing (not used here), so I have to run them manually on my local project. But yeah, I like clean and well designed code.

Comment: It is so terrible that unit testing be so unconsidered while that is a so powerful/efficient practice.

Comment: @davidxxx You know the motto "deliver! deliver! deliver! ... fix! fix! fix!". Apparently they like that.

Answer (score 1):

The issue I can see is `ProposalUpdateDefaultService` doing too many things and know too much. It accepts a lot of services, creates steps and executes the steps instead it should only accept a single parameter object and update without knowing what are the steps.

First I would try to reduce the parameters from the constructor `ProposalUpdateDefaultService` by creating a separate class which will contain the services and converters.

```
public class ServicesAndConverters {
    ComplexService complexService;
    OtherComplexService otherComplexService

    //...

}
```

In that way the code can be much cleaner

```
public class ProposalUpdateDefaultService implements ProposalUpdateService {
    ServiceAndConverters serviceAndConvert;

    public ProposalUpdateDefaultService(final ServiceAndConverters serviceAndConverters) {
        this.serviceAndConvert = serviceAndConverters; //maybe group them in two different class??
    }

}
```

Now the second issue I can see to create steps in the `ProposalUpdateDefaultService` itself. This should be responsibility of different class. Something like below

```
 public class ProposalUpdateDefaultService implements ProposalUpdateService {
         ServiceAndConverters serviceAndConvert;
         StepCreator stepCreator = new StepCreator();

         public ProposalUpdateDefaultService(final ServiceAndConverters serviceAndConverters) {
             this.serviceAndConvert = serviceAndConverters;
             stepCreator.createSteps(this.serviceAndConverter);
         }

     }
```

And the `StepCreator` class should look like this

```
public class StepCreator implements ProposalUpdateService {
        private final ProposalStep<Proposal> stepOne;
        private final ProposalStep<Proposal> stepTwo;
        private final ProposalStep<ProposalTypeTwo> stepThree;
        private final ProposalStep<Proposal> stepFour;

        public void createSteps(ServiceAndConverters s) {
                // do the step processing here
        }

}
```

Now `ProposalUpdateDefaultService` can execute the steps without knowing what is the steps and which service need to execute

```
@Override
public void updateProposal(final ProposalTypeOne proposal) {
   stepCreator.getStepOne().process(proposal);
   stepCreator.getStepTwo().process(proposal);

   if (...) {
      stepCreator.getStepFour().process(proposal);
   }
}
```

Comment: I think encapsulating the steps may be a good idea, but moving all the parameters inside another object is just a placebo for me. I mean it doesn't alleviate the problem because that new object must be constructed in the same way.

Comment: The "Steps" object may use the Chain of responbility pattern to organize the steps.

Comment: It is similar to parameter object pattern. I feel it is more readable than passing individual in the constructor. When client going to create the instance of parameter object it is easy to see what needs to be done rather than creating instance of worker class which accepts a lot of parameter.  See https://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html

Comment: The example you linked (DateRange) is pretty defined and cannot cause confusion. In this case there would be too much imho. Also, does the StepCreator class accept those Step(s) or it create them internally? If it does accept them as dependency it is just a copy of ProposalUpdateDefaultService

Comment: `StepCreator` class will create the steps internally by accessing the services and hold all steps. Then you can access steps like `stepCreator.getStepOne()` to use in your worker class

Comment: I can imagine, your code can be more complex. These suggestions are just to see the code you shared

Comment: Sure, and thanks! I'm just saying that to me wrapping dependencies in another object is not THE solution. It might be better because if a dependency is added or removed the constructors signature won't change, but it is also a bit dangerous. I prefer always seeing what is required, I don't like having to inspect another object.